# Is it possible to fill a 2d grid with a given group of rectangles, so that every rectangle can trace a ortogonal path to a single point in the grid.

Tags: general-topology, geometry, path-connected

While playing a city builder game, I noticed that the area of the buildings I can place on the game map is lower than the area of the map itself, since I need to place the roads that connect all buildings to a central block, and they occupy space themselves.

That brings the question: Is it possible to predict, for a certain group of rectangles, if it's possible to tile a given finite plane while keeping the rule that every rectangle has a point in their perimeter that can trace an unobstructed path to an arbitrary point?

I have played around for an afternoon, but came up blank. One can easily eliminate any group that contains a total area larger than the plane, or an individual rectangle with a dimension larger than the plane's, but I have not been able to think of a general solution.

Comment: It will probably help users respond if you make your description a bit more rigorous. What do you mean specifically by a rectangle having "a point in their perimeter that can trace an unobstructed path to an arbitrary point"? Also, when mathematicians say "tiling" they often mean filling a space with shapes in a way that has no overlaps or gaps. Is this what you intend, or do you still want to leave space for "roads"?

Comment: The problem of just deciding if we can fit all rectangles (without taking into account paths) is already a hard combinatorial problem (NP-complete), known as 2d bin packing.

Comment: @Tom Space for roads, yes. Sorry for being unclear, I don't really have the proper vocabulary to express this, so allow me give a different perspective: Is there an arrangement of blocks so that all blocks have a point in their perimeter that touches an unoccupied space, and all unoccupied space is contiguous?

Comment: @caduk Thank you for the insight, taking that into consideration there is a good chance this task is impossible. Is there any material you recommend on 2d bin packing?